# The Installer could not find Models of cms app in Django-CMS

Tags: django, django-models, django-cms

I have installed django-cms in my hosting. But there is a problem. That's when I make syncdb,
all my apps are synced, **cms** app is not. Although I have declared full 
enough in the settings. It is also not error at all. 
Someone help me. Thanks a lot!

> (1146, "Table '***.cms_page' doesn't
>   exist")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are good news. I have overcome this error. In fact, this error is because I use **the old version of MySQL-Python**. It is not compatible with Django-CMS 2.0.

To upgrade the MySQL-Python 1.2.3c1, please visit: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/ 
(Do not use easy_install)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you include it in your INSTALLED_APPS list before running syncdb?

It might also help if you post that snippet from your settings.py file, as well as your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

I want to emphasize that I have added all the app before making 
syncdb. Below is the text file (I copied from folder Example of 
Django-CMS source).

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "cms.context_processors.media",
)

INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',

    #'django.contrib.csrf.middleware.CsrfMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.multilingual.MultilingualURLMiddleware',
    #'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',

)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'projectname.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'tagging',

    'cms',
    'publisher',

    'cms.plugins.text',
    'cms.plugins.picture',
    'cms.plugins.file',
    'cms.plugins.flash',
    'cms.plugins.link',
    'cms.plugins.snippet',
    'cms.plugins.googlemap',
    'cms.plugins.teaser',
    'cms.plugins.video',
    'cms.plugins.twitter',
    'mptt',
    'reversion',

    'south',

    'projectname.sampleapp',

)

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en"

gettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
)

CMS_LANGUAGE_CONF = {
    'en':['en'],
}

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('index.html', gettext('default')),
    ('nice.html', gettext('nice one')),
    ('cool.html', gettext('cool one')),
    ('long-folder-long/long-template-name.html', gettext('long')),
)

CMS_APPLICATIONS_URLS = (
    ('sampleapp.urls', 'Sample application'),
    ('sampleapp.urlstwo', 'Second sample application'),
)

CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {                        
    'right-column': {
        "plugins": ('FilePlugin', 'FlashPlugin', 'LinkPlugin', 'PicturePlugin', 'TextPlugin', 'SnippetPlugin'),
        "extra_context": {"theme":"16_16"},
        "name":gettext("right column")
    },

    'body': {
        "plugins": ("VideoPlugin", "TextPlugin", ),
        "extra_context": {"theme":"16_5"},
        "name":gettext("body"),
    },
    'fancy-content': {
        "plugins": ('TextPlugin', 'LinkPlugin'),
        "extra_context": {"theme":"16_11"},
        "name":gettext("fancy content"),
    },
}


CMS_NAVIGATION_EXTENDERS = (('projectname.categories.navigation.get_nodes', 'Categories'),)

CMS_SOFTROOT = True
CMS_MODERATOR = True
CMS_PERMISSION = True
CMS_REDIRECTS = True
CMS_SEO_FIELDS = True
CMS_MENU_TITLE_OVERWRITE = True
CMS_HIDE_UNTRANSLATED = False


try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this solution was 'python manage.py syncdb' was not creating the CMS tables, so rather I had to use 'python manage.py syncdb --all' which then created all of the necessary tables.